# 配列を正規表現に置き換えて表現したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

例えば、以下のようなタンパク質、つまり20種類のアミノ酸（文字）からなる任意長の配列を考えます。

```
MNIFEMLRIDELRLKIYKDTEYYTIIHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIRNTNVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRILRNAKLKPVYD
```

実は、タンパク質の配列中には、任意長のアミノ酸配列からなる特定のパターンが含まれることがあります。このパターンはモチーフと呼ばれ、正規表現で与えられます。以下はその一例です（実際には1000以上あります）。

```
N[^P][ST][^P]
[RK]{2}.[ST]
[ST].[RK]
[ST].{2}[DE]
.G[RK][RK]
C.[DN].{4}[FY].C.C
RGD
```

ここで上記のタンパク質を、元のアミノ酸のみの配列から、モチーフにあたる部分は上記の正規表現に変換し、モチーフではない部分は元のアミノ酸のままで表現したいです。ただし、なるべく元のタンパク質の長さが短くなるように表現したいです。

このようなことを実現するためには、Pythonでどのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えば `TFRD` という部分配列が含まれている場合、`[ST].[RK]` と `[ST].{2}[DE]` のどちらにも一致しますが、マッチする文字列がヨリ長い `[ST].{2}[DE]` で置き換えるという事でしょうか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。この場合は、[ST].{2}[DE] で置き換えたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

正規表現がマッチしたところをその正規表現自体で変換したい、という理解で間違いなければ、

```
import re

motifs = ['N[^P][ST][^P]',
          '[RK]{2}.[ST]',
          '[ST].[RK]',
          '[ST].{2}[DE]',
          '.G[RK][RK]',
          'C.[DN].{4}[FY].C.C',
          'RGD']

amino = "MNIFEMLRIDELRLKIYKDTEYYTIIHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIRNTNVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRILRNAKLKPVYD"
for motif in motifs:
    amino = re.sub(motif, motif, amino)
print(amino)
# MNIFEMLRIDELRLKIYKDTEYYTIIHLLTKSPSLNAAK[ST].{2}[DE]KAIRNTNVI[ST].{2}[DE]AEKLFNQDVDAAVRILRNAKLKPVYD
```

でいけるはずです。

与えられた例だと、マッチするモチーフは一つしかなく、文字列が短くなるわけでもないですが。。。

Comment: 上の例が悪かったかもしれません。すみません。とりあえずこのコードで処理してみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。